# getting error when run the JUNIT via gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am getting the error beloe when using gradle to run Junit.

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':apilink:testCompile'.
> Could not find powermock-module-junit4:version:1.6.0.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an invalid dependency declared that cannot be found. The incorrect part is `'powermock-module-junit4:version:1.6.0'`. This should instead be `'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.0'`.